# I am missing an alias for a derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I know, this question has been asked very often but I know my error, I know how I could fix it, but I can´t find the point where the error is. In my opinion, all the subqueries have different and unique names, I even gave the columns different names then the subqueries. Any help would be appreciated. Where is the point I am missing an alias?

Whenever I am trying to run this query I get the response "Every derived table must have its alias", which is an understandable error message, but I can't figure out where my error is located.

```
SELECT
  mso.entity_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(msh.comment) AS comment,
  msoa.lastname,
  base_grand_total,
  mso.created_at,
  mso.status,
  marketplace_order_id AS amazon_order_id,
  clvData.recurrenceRate,
  clvData.avgRepRate
FROM
  mag_sales_flat_order AS mso
  LEFT JOIN mag_sales_flat_order_status_history AS msh ON mso.entity_id = msh.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN mag_sales_flat_order_address AS msoa ON mso.entity_id = msoa.parent_id
  left join (
    select
      cast(((cet.cec - cnt.cnc) / cst.csc) AS decimal(6, 2)) as recurrenceRate,
      avg(repRate.countedOrders) AS avgRepRate
    from(
        Select
          *,
          (
            select
              count(customer_email) AS csc
            from
              mag_sales_flat_order
            where
              created_at between '2017-01-01'
              and '2017-12-31'
          ) AS cst,
          (
            select
              count(customer_email) AS cec
            from
              mag_sales_flat_order
            where
              created_at between '2017-01-01'
              and '2020-12-31'
          ) AS cet,
          (
            select
              count(mso_new.customer_email) AS cnc
            from
              (
                select
                  *
                from
                  mag_sales_flat_order
                where
                  created_at between '2018-01-01'
                  and current_date()
              ) AS mso_new
              left join (
                select
                  *
                from
                  mag_sales_flat_order
                where
                  created_at between '2017-01-01'
                  and '2017-12-31'
              ) AS mso_old on mso_new.customer_email = mso_old.customer_email
          )) AS cnt
          join (
            select
              customer_email,
              count(grand_total) as countedOrders,
              sum(grand_total) as summedOrders
            from
              mag_sales_flat_order
            group by
              customer_email
          ) AS repRate on cl.customer_email = repRate.customer_email
      ) AS clvData on mso.customer_email = clvData.customer_email
    WHERE
      store_id IN({$store['id']})
      AND (
        mso.status = 'complete'
        OR mso.status = 'closed'
        OR mso.status = 'processing'
        OR mso.status = 'exported'
        OR mso.status LIKE 'pending%'
      )
      AND (
        DATE_FORMAT(mso.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '$begin_date'
      )
      AND (
        DATE_FORMAT(mso.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '$end_date'
      )
    GROUP BY
      entity_id;
```

Comment: I'd guess you need a table alias in row 3 from the end. And a JOIN condition too.

Comment: Do you mean just before the last "Group by"? But this isn`t a subquery so it should´t need an alias. And I don't get why there shoul be a join in your opinion. It´s just the where clause, i used the joins before.

Comment: You're right. That's the WHERE clause...  But just before the WHERE clause?

Comment: I just tested the alias you mentioned and it sadly did not solve it. Could be not the right solution but there could also be more than on subquery not given an alias.

Comment: Doesn't the error message include a row number too?

Comment: Ok, I identified 1 bracket which I added wrong. But still one of the subqueries doesn´t have an alias. The bracket just before the where clause has to be deleted, I will update my post asap

Comment: No, sadly not. It just says the following: "Curl Response :{"response":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias"}"

Comment: There's a problem close to `) AS cnt`. The bracket too much?

Comment: Nope, it isn´t too much, but it seems to be in the wrong spot. I corrected it, the issue seems to be solved. The new error is : "Curl Response :{"response":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['id'] })\r\n AND (\r\n mso.status = 'complete'\r\n OR mso.status =' at line 75"}". But it seems to be unrelated to this issue with missing alias names. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use `JOIN`?

Comment: Where do you mean exactly? I didn´t get where you and jarlh would recommend a join. Or do you mean the simple join instead of the left join? What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    mso.entity_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(msh.comment) AS comment,
    msoa.lastname,
    base_grand_total,
    mso.created_at,
    mso.status,
    marketplace_order_id AS amazon_order_id,
    clvData.recurrenceRate,
    clvData.avgRepRate
FROM mag_sales_flat_order AS mso
LEFT JOIN mag_sales_flat_order_status_history AS msh ON mso.entity_id = msh.parent_id
LEFT JOIN mag_sales_flat_order_address AS msoa ON mso.entity_id = msoa.parent_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT cast(((cet.cec - cnt.cnc) / cst.csc) AS decimal(6, 2)) as recurrenceRate, avg(repRate.countedOrders) AS avgRepRate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
        (
            SELECT count(customer_email) AS csc
            FROM mag_sales_flat_order
            WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
        ) AS cst,
        (
            SELECT count(customer_email) AS cec
            FROM mag_sales_flat_order
            WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
        ) AS cet,
        (
            SELECT count(mso_new.customer_email) AS cnc
            FROM
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM mag_sales_flat_order
                WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND getdate()
            ) AS mso_new
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM mag_sales_flat_order
                WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
            ) AS mso_old on mso_new.customer_email = mso_old.customer_email
        ) AS cnt          
    ) as cl
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT customer_email, count(grand_total) as countedOrders, sum(grand_total) as summedOrders
        FROM mag_sales_flat_order
        GROUP BY customer_email
    ) AS repRate on cl.customer_email = repRate.customer_email
) AS clvData on mso.customer_email = clvData.customer_email
WHERE store_id IN({ $ store ['id'] })
    AND
    (
        mso.status = 'complete'
        OR mso.status = 'closed'
        OR mso.status = 'processing'
        OR mso.status = 'exported'
        OR mso.status LIKE 'pending%'
    )
    AND
    (
        DATE_FORMAT(mso.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '$begin_date'
    )
    AND
    (
        DATE_FORMAT(mso.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '$end_date'
    )
GROUP BY entity_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. It solved the issue with the alias, but I still don´t get where my error was. Would you be so nice and tell me, please?

Comment: Hello, it was missing this line:
`) as cl`
and ther was an extra `)`